# How should I export data to mysql and use delimiter when reading in a file?

Tags: mysql, bash

I know on the mysql command line how to export into a delimited file, but I'm not sure how echo this process when reading in an sql file.

For example, I'm trying to have this behavior:

```
mysql -ume -pme db_name < select.sql > into outfile 'results.csv' fields terminated by '|';
```

I KNOW this won't work, but I can't just 'sed' and replace all the tabs with pipes because some of the field contents might have tabs in them.

And I can't -e with the query because the queries are way too long and unruly to paste into the mysql command line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can't do it one line. you'll have to load your file, then do `select ...` query separately with the outfile stuff.